# Class in div not reflected correctly in the HTML after getting created

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML form to add names and if there are additional names required addition there is button to click which creates and new div and inside it an input and a label is created.

I have managed to get the logic to work but the problem is that the "form-outline" is not correctly reflected in the page although it is showing in the page script when created.

Here is the HTML which will explain more:

```
                <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                  <input type="text" id="ownerName1" class="form-control" />
                  <label class="form-label" for="typeText"
                    >Name of Owner(s)/Major Shareholders:</label
                  >
                </div>
                <button
                  onclick="newShareholder()"
                  type="button"
                  class="mb-2 btn btn-primary btn-sm ripple-surface"
                >
                  Add Shareholders
                </button>
```

Here is the script

```
              <script>
                var buttons = 2;
                const button = document.querySelector("button");
                function newShareholder() {
                  var div = document.createElement("div");
                  div.className = "form-outline mb-4";

                  var input = document.createElement("input");
                  input.type = "text";
                  input.id = "ownerName" + buttons;
                  input.className = "form-control";
                  document.body.appendChild(input);
                  buttons++;

                  var label = document.createElement("label");
                  label.className = "form-label";
                  label.innerHTML = "Name of Owner(s)/Major Shareholders:";
                  div.appendChild(input);
                  div.appendChild(label);
                  button.parentElement.insertBefore(div, button);
                }
              </script>
```

Here is the print screen which I am struggling with there is a boarder form in the original but not in the new created one.

[image]

Also in the console log there is this error showing:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at o.value (mdb.min.js:19)
    at o.value (mdb.min.js:19)
    at mdb.min.js:19
    at u (mdb.min.js:19)
    at o.value (mdb.min.js:19)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (mdb.min.js:19)
    at HTMLDocument.t (mdb.min.js:19)
```

Comment: You can debug code on browser to check where is the issue. Then check why this issue is appearing. This is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var buttons = 2;
        

        function newShareholder() {
            var button = document.querySelector("button");//moved inside function.
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.className = "form-outline mb-4";

            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "text";
            input.id = "ownerName" + buttons;
            input.className = "form-control";
            document.body.appendChild(input);
            buttons++;

            var label = document.createElement("label");
            label.className = "form-label";
            label.innerHTML = "Name of Owner(s)/Major Shareholders:";
            div.appendChild(input);
            div.appendChild(label);
            button.parentElement.insertBefore(div, button);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: It did not change anything the same effect the form outline is not showing